# Configure APT to also cache all dependencies of a package?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

**I want to know if there is a way to configure APT to also download all the dependencies (as deep as the dependency spiral goes) of a package and cache them in `/var/cache/apt/archives`.**

**EDIT:**
It seems that using `apt` instead of `apt-get` causes no caches to be downloaded. Can anybody confirm this please?

---

**WHAT I TRIED:**

I tried installing `texlive-full` with `--install-recommends` and saw that there are 155 packages to install but APT only cached `texlive-full.deb`.

Possible solutions:

1. Ask apt to install all those 155 packages which would cause them all to be cached. **But this works only for dependencies that are one level deep.**
2. Use `apt-rdepends`:

   `apt-get --print-uris --yes -d --reinstall install "$1" | grep "http://" |  awk '{print$1}' | xargs -I'{}' echo {} | tee "$2"`

   This spits out the url of all dependencies of given packages (`$1`) to a file (`$2`) which can then be input to `wget`.

Although 2 is the most feasible solution, it costs me bandwidth by having to download packages twice. And I don't want to create a local apt-mirror using `apt-mirror`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely the easiest method:

```
apt download $(apt-rdepends <package>|grep -v "^ ")
```